# Ubuntu doesn't show hard drive partitions properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

I first had Windows 8.1 on my laptop installed and now I'm trying to add Ubuntu 15.10 and be able to dual boot. I have freed up some space and partitioned my hard drive for the Ubuntu installation.

Windows shows:

```
C:/ - 100GB (Windows 8 installation)
E:/ - 430~GB
F:/ - 430~GB
```

when I run the Ubuntu installer, it shows these:

```
/dev/sda1 - 1 MB (usage: unknown)
/dev/sda2 - 104 MB (usage: unknown)
/dev/sda3 - 105'549 MB (usage: unknown)
/dev/sda4 - 894'548 MB (usage 0 MB)
```

Even the usage is wrong as I only have the F:/ disk completely empty which is around 430 GB, the rest is used up mostly

I tried running

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

which returns:

```
    Partition table scan:
 MBR: MBR only
 BSD: not present
 APM: not present
 GPT: not present

*************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory.
*************************************************************
```

This doesn't change anything though, what can I do?

Comment: You might want to ask this on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The output you get is correct. You are only listing the first hard drive (your C: drive) which is `/dev/sda` on Linux, and the numbers  you see after `/dev/sda` are partitions.

It's perfectly normal to have a system partition on a Windows drive which is about 100MB, however, I do not know why you have two. Probably not an issue.

I suggest using `fdisk -l` or `gdisk -l` to see what hardd rives you actually have, and then, should you want to modify them, just use `fdisk /dev/sdX` where X is the letter of the hard drive (or gdisk if your drives have GPT layouts). Be careful though as it doesn't take much to mess something up if you have sensitive data